# Segue Right Left transition

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have some code This is the code that describes the transition from left to right

```
class AGSegue: UIStoryboardSegue 
override func perform() {
    let sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController 
    let destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController 
    // Creates a screenshot of the old viewcontroller
    let duplicatedSourceView: UIView = sourceViewController.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)

    // the screenshot is added above the destinationViewController
    destinationViewController.view.addSubview(duplicatedSourceView)

    sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: {
        // it is added above the destinationViewController
        destinationViewController.view.addSubview(duplicatedSourceView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            // slides the sourceViewController to the right
            duplicatedSourceView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sourceViewController.view.frame.size.width, 0)
            }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                duplicatedSourceView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })

}
```

}

I need only a transition from right to left

Answer (score 0):

To give the transition animation effect remove those hectic work which you have done and go for `UINavigationViewController` it will allows to push and pop animation for view and maintain the low disk space for every transition. If you want right to left transition for `UIViewController` then push that view into `UINavigationViewController` and for left to right transition pop view to root view.